# Uniformly convergence and Uniformly continous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f: R \to R$ be a function. Define $x \in R$ and $n \in Z^+$ and

$\phi_n(x) = \sup \big\{ |f(s) - f(t)| : s,t \in (x-\frac{1}{n}, x + \frac{1}{n}) \big\} $

Prove that the sequence ${\phi_n}$ converges uniformly to $0$ if and only if $f$ is uniformly continuous.

---

Here is what I did:

Proof: ($\Rightarrow$) Suppose the sequence $\{ \phi_n \}$ converges uniformly to $0$. Then for $\epsilon > 0$, $n > N(\epsilon)$ imply

$| \phi_n(x)- 0| = \sup \big\{ |f(s) - f(t)| : s,t \in (x-\frac{1}{n}, x + \frac{1}{n}) \big\}  < \epsilon $

So for all $ s,t \in (x-\frac{1}{n}, x + \frac{1}{n})$ , $ | s- t| < \delta < \frac{2}{n} $ then $|f(s) - f(t)| < \epsilon$. Hence, $f$ is uniformly continuous.

($\Leftarrow$)Now suppose that $f$ is uniformly continuous.  Then for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exist a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $s ,t \in (x-\frac{1}{n}, x + \frac{1}{n}) $ we have $|f(s) - f(t)| < \epsilon$. Then

$| \phi_n(x)| = \sup \big\{ |f(s) - f(t)| : s,t \in (x-\frac{1}{n}, x + \frac{1}{n}) \big\}  < \epsilon $.

Thus $\phi_n$ converges to $0$ uniformly.

---

Can you point out if there is a mistake and help me to fix it if that's possible. Thank you!

Comment: Both are not correct. First: What is $x$ here? You have to show that for _all_ $s,t$ with $|s-t| < 2/n$ we have $|f(s)-f(t)| < \epsilon$. Second: Also here:what is $x$?

Comment: I am sorry but I am not sure what do you mean "what is x here?"

Comment: It's exactly what it says. What is $x$? You do not specify that. It may be some complex number, for example. Neither do you say whether your claims hold for some $x$ or for all $x$...

Comment: $x \in R$ and it holds for all $x$

Comment: The appearance of $x$ is fine.  With this definition we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \phi_n(x) = \omega_f(x)$, the oscillation of the function $f$ at $x$.

Comment: @RRL: No, it obviously is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of the forward implication requires some modification.

Since $\phi_n \to 0$ uniformly, for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N_\epsilon$ such that if $n \geqslant N_\epsilon$ then for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $\phi_n(x) < \epsilon$. This implies that for any given $x$, if $s,t \in (x - 1/N_\epsilon, x + 1/N_\epsilon)$ then $|f(s) - f(t)| \leqslant \phi_{N_\epsilon}(x) <  \epsilon$.

Consider any $s,t \in \mathbb{R}$. Take $x = s$ and $\delta_\epsilon = 1/N_\epsilon$.  Then if $|t-s| < \delta_\epsilon$, we have both $s,t \in (s - 1/N_\epsilon, s + 1/N_\epsilon)$  and $|f(s) - f(t)| < \epsilon$.

Based on what was used for this argument, you should be able to fix your proof of the reverse implication.